# Source not updated when changing UI

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a problem when binding a Textbox to the Value of a Station Object. The values are displayed correctly, but when i edit the values on screen the Source isn't updated. What am i doing wrong?

```
    public LineControl(ArrayList cells)
    {


        InitializeComponent();
        this.cells = cells;
        foreach (Cell c in cells)
        {
            AccordionItem aci = new AccordionItem();

            StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
            aci.Content = sp;
            DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();

            if(c.Stations!=null)
            foreach (Station s in c.Stations)
            {

                TextBox t = new TextBox();
                t.DataContext = s;
                 Binding binding = new Binding();
                 binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
                 binding.Source = s;
                 binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Value");
                 binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
                 t.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
                 //t.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(t_TextChanged);

                sp.Children.Add(t);
            }
            acc.Items.Add(aci);
        }
}
```

My Station Class looks like

```
class Station
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set;  }

}
```

In my XAML there isn't anything significant:

```
     <UserControl x:Class="Knowles_ShiftreportEditor.LineControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:toolkit="clr-   namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="100">
<Grid>

    <toolkit:Accordion Width="100"  Name="acc" SelectionMode="One" Loaded="acc_Loaded">
    </toolkit:Accordion>
</Grid>
```

Comment: If you mean a change on a station in code is not reflected in the UI then it's INotifyPropertyChanged as @avanek says. If not please also show the XAML

Comment: I have inserted my XAML, but there is not really much to see...

Comment: But which way round is it not working ? 1. Change on screen not reflected in code or 2. Change in code not reflected on screen?

Comment: 1. Change on screen not reflected in code

Comment: It's not INotifyPropertyChanged if it's from screen to code

Comment: I've implemented a slightly simpler solution (not using accordion and just adding a list of stations i created in the code behind and binding them to text boxes using your code and adding to a window grid). This correctly captures updates from screen to code. So things to look at include: accordion, what are 'cells' and how do they contain stations? It's most likely to be how that station collection is defined

Comment: So the code-side isn't updating at all? Even after the textbox loses focus or you tab out of the textbox? If you are expecting the binding to update on the TextChanged event (as I see commented out above), you will have to explicitly set the update source trigger.

Comment: I got i to work - but i have no idea what was wrong...

Thanks guys for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [implementing INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) on your `Station` class? Also, what is the type used for your `Stations` collection at the top of your `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface in `Station` class. So, your `Station` class should look like this:

```
public class Station : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int value;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return this.id; }
        set
        {
            this.id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    public String Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set
        {
            this.name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't solve my Problem yet. I think you got my problem wrong: Changes in the UI don't reflect to the source and not the other way around.